# How to export Memgraph graph as a series of Cypher statements, so I can use it to import the data to another instance or Neo4j?

Tags: memgraphdb

I have a *Memgraph* database running.

How to export *Memgraph* graph as a series of *Cypher* statements, so I can use it to import to another instance?

I was reading the documentation and only found how to [Import Cypher](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/import-data#queries), but not how to Export Cypher.

I would like a way to import/export as a text file containing the Cypher statements that I can use to transfer data into Neo4j/Memgraph server instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can export your graph by using [Memgraph Lab](https://memgraph.com/product/lab). If using the `memgraph/memgraph-platform` Docker image, you should be able to access Memgraph Lab locally in your browser at `http://localhost:3000/` .

While on the ***Overview*** tab, search for the option ***Export database*** in the upper right corner.

[image: Screenshot]

It will download the `graph.cypherl` file

Answer (score 1):

You can export your graph by using [Memgraph Lab](https://memgraph.com/product/lab). If using the `memgraph/memgraph-platform` Docker image, you should be able to access Memgraph Lab locally in your browser at `http://localhost:3000/`. If not, you probably use desktop version of Memgraph Lab.

Here are the simple steps how to export your database to the `cypherl` file (Memgraph Lab version > 2.0.0):

1. Select Import & Export tab
2. Input the file name at the Export data section
3. Click on Export Data button

Once the data is finished downloading you'll have `my_graph.cypherl` locally.

[image: memgraph lab export]